# Resources for designing math degree programs

Tags: undergraduate-education, graduate-education, resource-request

I'd like to know where I can find resources which are helpful when one has to design or improve grad and undergrad degree programs in pure and applied mathematics.
In particular, I'm searching for up-to-date field studies containing data and/or analyses on career opportunities for math graduates who focused on dynamical systems and mathematical physics.

I know SIAM has released something of this kind, I'm searching some more material.

Just for clarity: I'm not necessarily asking for material released from Universities, rather for resources produced by international societies for the development of mathematics, governments, non-profit companies etc...

Thank you!

(I also asked this on Academia Stack Exchange, but someone suggested this is a better place.)

Comment: This will be highly dependent on the country in which you are working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For undergrad, the MAA put out "Guidelines for Programs and Departments in Undergraduate Mathematical Sciences" about 20 years ago. We used this when preparing for program review about a decade ago and it was still relevant then.

https://maa.org/programs-and-communities/member-communities/committee-on-departmental-review/guidelines-programs-departments

**Update:** Lest it gets buried in the comments, Brian Borchers points out:

> There's a 2015 update that is still quite relevant. Presumably a new
> report will come out in 2025.
> https://maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/curriculum-department-guidelines-recommendations/cupm/2015-cupm-curriculum-guide

Thanks for pointing this out!!

Comment: Many thanks...although 20 years ago looks really too old for my purpose.

Comment: There's a 2015 update that is still quite relevant.  Presumably a new report will come out in 2025. https://maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/curriculum-department-guidelines-recommendations/cupm/2015-cupm-curriculum-guide

Comment: I will also note that the individual course reports are also useful when designing or redesigning a course within an existing program:  https://maa.org/node/790342/